# Check if 3D touch is supported and enabled on the iOS9 device

Tags: ios, iphone, 3dtouch

I tried to access the trait collection and check "forceTouchCapability", but "forceTouchCapability" simply checks to see if the device is iOS 9.0 or greater.

So, this means that on any device with iOS 9, force touch is 'available'. I need to a way to check if 3D touch is actually supported on the users device (iPhone 6s) and I need to make sure that the 3D Touch option is actually enabled in the accessibility settings.

Comment: That's bad news - have you tried it on the 9.1 beta?

Comment: No, we are adding 3D touch capability to an app we are going to be releasing in a few days, so we are aiming for 9.0. Using Xcode 7.0.

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: From what I understand, you are on the right track with accessing the trait collection and using `forceTouchCapability`. This link seems helpful/relevant: http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-use-3d-touch-in-ios-9-part-1-peek-and-pop/

Comment: On what basis are you stating that `forceTouchCapability` only checks to see if the device is iOS 9 or greater?

Comment: We have 3 devices - an iPad Air 1 (No 3d touch, running iOS 9.0), iPhone 6 (No 3d touch, running iOS 8.3), iPhone 6s (3d touch, running iOS 9.0).

Comment: forceTouchCapability returns: true on iPad, true on iPhone 6s, false on iPhone 6.

Comment: I am writing a plugin for a Unity3D game. To get access to the Unity View, I am fetching the last view using this: 

UIView *UnityView = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] subviews] lastObject];

and returning this:

 [[UnityView traitCollection] forceTouchCapability];

Comment: I think I just realised my error - I am returning forceTouchCapability, assuming it is a 'bool'. It is actually an enum, and I guess it was being cast to a bool - returning true when it equalled '1' (UIForceTouchCapabilityUnavailable = 1)

Comment: I was just going to point out that the return value is not a `BOOL`.

Comment: Amateur mistake :-) I've answered my own question

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I was accidentally casting `forceTouchCapability` to a `BOOL` (using it as a return value to my method that was set to return a boolean). I needed to check if `forceTouchCapability` was equal to `UIForceTouchCapabilityAvailable`.

Instead of:

```
return [[MyView traitCollection] forceTouchCapability];
```

I need:

```
return [[MyView traitCollection] forceTouchCapability] == UIForceTouchCapabilityAvailable;
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you need to properly guard this code if your app supports iOS 8.x or earlier in addition to iOS 9.

Comment: Yep! Thanks, already done :) Ran into that properly already hehe.

Comment: swift version http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33686640/swift-check-if-3d-touch-is-possible?lq=1

Comment: @Prodigga hey I do not have a 3D touch device I wanted to ask: Although it returns NotAvailable for device not supporting 3D Touch, does it also return NotAvailable for devices with 3D touch but disabled in settings?

Answer (score 12):

If you implement this in `UIViewController`, the timing matters. Checking in `viewDidLoad` will return `Unknown` when it will return `Available` later in the lifecycle.

```
- (void)traitCollectionDidChange:(nullable UITraitCollection *)previousTraitCollection {
    [self checkForForceTouch];
}

- (void)checkForForceTouch {
    if ([self.traitCollection respondsToSelector:@selector(forceTouchCapability)] &&
        self.traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == UIForceTouchCapabilityAvailable) {
        NSLog(@"Force touch found");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you -- this was my problem!

Comment: it 3d touch disable from settings, how to check this

Comment: @Shohrab This method will automatically detect this.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes we want just to have `forceTouchCapability` value right now synchronously and don't want to wait for `traitCollectionDidChange:` event. In that case, we can use pretty stupid function like this:

```
public func forceTouchCapability() -> UIForceTouchCapability {
    return UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.traitCollection.forceTouchCapability ?? .Unknown
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if ([MyView respondsToSelector:@selector(traitCollection)] &&
    [MyView.traitCollection respondsToSelector:@selector(forceTouchCapability)] &&
    MyView.traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == UIForceTouchCapabilityAvailable) {
        return YES;
    }
```

My point is, if you are supporting **iOS 7** and **iOS 8** as well, remember to check for both the conditions: `[MyView respondsToSelector:@selector(traitCollection)]` and `[MyView.traitCollection respondsToSelector:@selector(forceTouchCapability)]`.

If you keep the first check, the app works fine on iOS 7 but crashes on iOS 8.
Basically, Apple introduced `traitCollection` property in iOS 8 but added `forceTouchCapability` property only in iOS 9.

from *UITraitCollection.h*:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UITraitCollection *traitCollection NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);

@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIForceTouchCapability forceTouchCapability NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(9_0);
```

PS: Learnt it the hard way, after app started to crash on App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.0 and 4.1.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Check device supports feature
        if self.traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .available {
        // Enable 3D Touch feature here
         } else {
        // Fall back to other non 3D feature
         }
      }
      override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        // Update the app's 3D Touch support
      if self.traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .available {
          // Enable 3D Touch feature here
      } else {
          // Fall back to other non 3D feature
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

following Valentin Shergin, updated for swift 4.2 if You need a sync call:

```
func forceTouchCapability() -> UIForceTouchCapability {
    return UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.traitCollection.forceTouchCapability ?? .unknown
}


func hasForceTouchCapability() -> Bool {
    return forceTouchCapability() == .available
}
```