# swift check if 3D Touch is possible

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch

In my app I will show settings, which only should be visible, if the device can 3D Touch. at the moment I check, if the device has ios9.

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *)
```

problem is, for example the iPhone 6 have iOS 9 but no 3D Touch. how can I check the possibility of 3D Touch with swift?

i found this post, but no swift solution:
[Check if 3D touch is supported and enabled on the iOS9 device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32814383/check-if-3d-touch-is-supported-and-enabled-on-the-ios9-device)

One more Question.
now i want to check if iOS 9 AND 3D Touch is available.
i try this:

```
if (#available(iOS 9.0, *)) AND (is3DTouchAvailable() == true) {
```

But i always get this error:

> Expected '{' after 'if' condition

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this swift code, `self` is referring to your `UIViewController`

```
func is3DTouchAvailable() -> Bool
{
    return self.traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == UIForceTouchCapability.Available
}
```

Comment: new question in my first post

Comment: what is your project minimum deployment target?

Comment: Could reduce the method to `return traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .Available`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `if self.traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == UIForceTouchCapability.Available` will work, just make sure to wrap it up in a `if #available(iOS 9, *)`

So an example for Peek and Pop:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if #available(iOS 9, *) {
            if (traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .Available) {
                if let collectionView = self.collectionView {
                    registerForPreviewingWithDelegate(self, sourceView: collectionView)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Moreover if you have an UITouch object (you can have it from method like `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, ...) if your device is 3D Touch capable the `touch.maximumPossibleForce` property will be higher than 0. Don't forget to wrap it up in a `if #available(iOS 9, *)` neither ;)

Feel free checkout this [Peek and Pop tutorial](http://blog.prolificinteractive.com/2015/12/09/3d-touch-behind-the-scenes-the-peek-and-pop-tutorial/) for more details, or this [sample of 3D Touch code](https://github.com/quentinR/PI3DTouch)

Comment: Hi Quentin, regarding your 4 answers in sequence please take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)