# iOS Check 3D Touch enable in settings

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, 3dtouch

In iPhone 6S, from `settings/Accessibility/3D Touch` user can able to enable/disable 3D touch option. I have tried `UIForceTouchCapability`to find out 3D touch enable or disable..

```
typedef NS_ENUM (NSInteger,
   UIForceTouchCapability ) {
   UIForceTouchCapabilityUnknown = 0,
   UIForceTouchCapabilityUnavailable = 1,
   UIForceTouchCapabilityAvailable = 2
};

on iPhone 6S and 3D Enable = `UIForceTouchCapabilityAvailable`
on iPhone 6S and 3D Disable = `UIForceTouchCapabilityUnavailable `
on iphone 6 = `UIForceTouchCapabilityUnavailable`
```

Is there any way to check, to find out 3D touch enable/disable from `settings/Accessibility/3D Touch` using objective C or Swift.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is trait collection. take a look at this so answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32814383/check-if-3d-touch-is-supported-and-enabled-on-the-ios9-device

Comment: i have check this but its not work as for iphone 6 & iphone 6s with disable 3d touch response UIForceTouchCapabilityUnavailable ..

Comment: I would recommend you to abstract your code from determining the exact device model. If you got `UIForceTouchCapabilityUnavailable` from the check, it does not matter what model of the device the app is running at. As Apple advises: Rely on capabilities, not on the device model.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have answered your question yourself.

If you want to find if a device with 3D touch capability has it turned OFF in settings, you can just find which device it is and manage if it returns `UIForceTouchCapabilityUnavailable` it means it is disabled in settings.